# Python pyplot not drawing lines when instructed

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm currently writing a piece of code to analyse some data however I've hit a small snag. Due to the large number of events present in analysis my group decided we should be taking means of each file and plotting those instead. When I've done this my function reads through the files and plots each point successfully however when I try to draw a line between the points of data nothing is drawn.

```
def plotEventSpeedVsDate(startYear):
    for filename in fileNameGenerator(startYear):
        date,linearSpeed,width,accel=readData(filename)
        xAxis=np.median(date)
        yAxis=np.mean(linearSpeed)
        plt.plot_date(xAxis, yAxis, '-', color='black')
```

it successfully plots the points but won't draw the lines instead when I run the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that each time you call `plot_date`, you are doing it for just one data point. If you collect all your dates and speeds in lists as you loop through your files, you can then plot those lists in one call to `plot_date` and connect the points with a line.

```
def plotEventSpeedVsDate(startYear):
    dates = []
    speeds = []
    for filename in fileNameGenerator(startYear):
        date,linearSpeed,width,accel=readData(filename)
        dates.append(np.median(date))
        speeds.append(np.mean(linearSpeed))

    plt.plot_date(dates, speeds, 'o-', color='black')
```

Comment: That's fantastic thank you! Seems so obvious now I look back on it.